# OSX visual diff tool that shows only changed lines with context

Tags: macos, diff

I'm looking for an OSX visual diff tool that gives me only the changes plus a few before/after lines in context. Essentially what you get with [unix diff context format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff#Context_format), but in a visual diff tool.

SourceTree does a great job of this, showing only the hunks that have changed ([example](http://www.sourcetreeapp.com/img/screenshots/st_feature_diff_thumbnail.png)). , but I would like to compare arbitrary directories and then their files.

I know there are several SO questions on OSX diff tools, but I can't seem to find this key feature in any of them. Or maybe I am missing a view option in one of them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do I always find the answers after I ask the question :/?

I found that DiffMerge has functionality close to what I would like. It's called "Show Differences With Context", but its not enabled until you switch to "Reference View". FYI, You can default to "Reference View" when opening by using the -ro2 (open file 2 as read only) flag, but you then you lose the ability to switch to the Edit View later.

That said, I would like a linear view like diff and SourceTree give you (DiffMerge has a side by side view). Would be great if someone knows of visual diff tool that does have that feature.

Comment: I was just about to answer that DiffMerge is pretty good. FYI, since you're looking specifically for a Mac app, you might have better luck on the [Apple StackExchange site](http://apple.stackexchange.com). Also, DiffMerge does work at the folder level. I'm on Windows now, and I can't remember if the menus are exactly the same, but I do know the functionality is there to compare directories. Look under File -> Open Folder Diff.

Comment: Thanks. I went with SO since that is kinds of diffs I want and because diff is so core to coding. I have found so far that the AskDifferent site is better for user-level questions. Too bad they don't support cross-posting (with enough reputation of course).

Comment: I've often wished for the ability to cross-post! I don't spend much time on the meta sites, but I bet it's been discussed into the ground...

Comment: @EmmyS, Thanks for pointing out it has a folder view also. I updated my answer.